# What does warning about trying to predict while register being accessed means?

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I've UVM verification environment.

In my test sequence I read (mirror) from REGA through FRONTDOOR (serial transaction) upon receiving interrupt.

In my scoreboard I've used `.predict` methods to updated expected values of REGA.

However I've following error:

```
Register "regmodel.REGA" value read from DUT (0x00000000000000AA) does not match mirrored value (0x0000000000000000)
```

Value read from DUT is correct (AA), and if I print value used in predict method then that is correct as well (AA)

However
In simulation I've following warning sometime before error:

```
Trying to predict value of register 'regmodel.REGA' while it is being accessed
```

My first thought was its because of race (predict and FRONTDOOR access), so I added delay before reading from register but it still happens to be same behavior.

I would like to know what exactly that warning means, and if I should change something

Comment: I'm using IUS (incisive) as my simulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really does mean that you're predicting your register during a read. If you call `predict(value)` and you're reading/writing the register at the same time, the read/write will error on the register model before your prediction completes (with front door access, anyway).

Personally, I'd make sure that your register read completes *fully* (by showing `regmodel.REGA.is busy() == 0`) before you start a predict operation.

If you want a little more info on UVM's register model, this link is excellent: http://cluelogic.com/2013/02/uvm-tutorial-for-candy-lovers-register-access-methods/

Comment: ok, but how would user know when predict is completed? Consider a checker updating predict values and sequence reading from registers (both are working in parallel threads and asynchronous to each other). Shouldn't scheduling take care of the situation? Or is there a flag indicating predict 'busy' ?

Comment: I had my ordering wrong, sorry. There's a field set inside the register model (`uvm_reg::m_is_busy`) during the read of regmodel.REGA. That field is checked by `uvm_reg::do_predict()`. If m_is_busy is set high when the predict begins, you'll get that "Trying to predict value of register regmodel.REGA while it is being accessed" message. As to how to get around that, you could use a semaphore accessible by both your asynchronous threads or call `regmodel.REGA.is_busy()` before you try to predict.

Comment: Thanks I'm gonna try this, I'm not working on the piece of code for next few days so will provide feedback later.

Comment: Exactly same issue i am also facing. I did not see a solution in this thread. 
i did a `wait(!regmodel.REGA.is_busy())` and it just hanged. 
Any way i can determine who is keeping the regmodel busy?

Answer (score 1):

When you call Predict function, it calls do_predict(). Do predict checks if the register is busy. If the register is found to be busy, do_predict() will not perform the predict operation.

So, user has to check the return value of the predict() function to check if the operation was done successfully

Predict returns 1 for SUCCESS and 0 for UN_SUCCESSFUL operation

You may write something like the following, to make sure the predict operation is done

```
  while (! (REGISTER.predict(<value>))); 


           OR
 Declare a standard task something like the following, and call it whenever you need



task dac_reg_base_seq::predict_register(uvm_reg REGISTER, bit [31:0] predict_value ); 
      uvm_reg register_temp;
      predict_register = 0; //Unsuccessful
      if (!$cast(register_temp, REGISTER))
      begin
        `uvm_fatal("NOT_UVM_REG_TYPE","Provided REGISTER is not of the correct type")
      end

     `uvm_info("PREDICT_REGISTER", $psprintf(" Starting the predict function setting register %s with value %h", register_temp.get_name(),predict_value), UVM_HIGH);
    while(1) begin
          if(register_temp.is_busy == 1) begin
           `uvm_info("PREDICT_REGISTER", $psprintf(" register %s  is busy ", register_temp.get_name()), UVM_HIGH);
         // Adding Delay to avoid simulater gets locked up here
         #1;
         continue;
          end
      else begin
            register_temp.predict(register_temp.get()| predict_value); 
            break;
          end
        end
     `uvm_info("PREDICT_REGISTER", $psprintf(" Done with updating the predict value to the register %s", register_temp.get_name()), UVM_HIGH);
endtask : predict_register
```

Comment: Could you please add a little more description about the explanation you provide?

Answer (score 0):

Here another example on how to wait until the front door is ready to accept predictions using is_busy function.

```
function void do_reset_key_registers(hmac_sha256_regblock parent_reg_block, uvm_reg      reg);
//$cast(parent_reg_block, this.get_parent());//this has been done outside
            fork 
                automatic uvm_reg reg=reg;//this is to copy the correct handle for each thread
                begin
                    if (reg.get_name=="inst_STATUS") begin
                        if  (reg.is_busy()) begin    wait(!reg.is_busy()); end//wait until this register is not busy 
                    end
                    assert( parent_reg_block.inst_STATUS.KEY_ERROR.predict(1));//key protect 0                                                    
                end
                begin
                    if (reg.get_name=="inst_KEY_0") begin
                        if  (reg.is_busy()) begin    wait(!reg.is_busy()); end//wait until this register is not busy 
                    end                    
                    assert( parent_reg_block.inst_KEY_0.KEY_0.predict(0));//reset KEYS 0
                end
            join_none
        endfunction: do_reset_key_registers
```